# Limit of a Sequence of Piecewise Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I was given the following function and asked to evaluate the following:

$$ f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  &   x\lt -\frac{1}{n} \\
nx, & -\frac{1}{n}\le x \le \frac{1}{n} \\
1, &x>\frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$$

Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$

To me this is approaching the signum function but how can I really find out what is happening as we look deeper into the sequence.  How can I really evaluate this limit?

Comment: If you think the answer is the signum function, then you think that for all $x>0$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=1$ and for all $x<0$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=-1$ and when $x=0$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(0)=0$. Now, you have explicit formulae for the sequence $f_n(x)$, which is just a sequence of numbers once you fix and $x$. So you need to unwind the definitions of the $f_n$ and "limit".

Comment: That helps.  Thank you